# Zend controller clarification

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i am new to Zend Framework,
i had an doubt on Zend controller, which is when an hyper link is clicked in one view page. that view page pass the some arguments to javascript that JavaScript perform some form action and post into controller,
that controller calls another view page. but i can't able to pass the value to view page, can anyone help me to solve this issue.

and my code is given below,

This is my JavaScript

```js
function getUserInfo(user_id, date)
{
 //window.location.href= base_url+"/timemanagement/emptimesheets/employeeactivity";
 // var locationUrl1= base_url+"/timemanagement/emptimesheets/employeeactivity.phtml";
 // window.location.href = locationUrl1;
 var form = document.createElement("form");
 var ele_user_id = document.createElement("input"); 
 var sel_date = document.createElement("input"); 
 form.method = "POST";
 //form.action = base_url+"/timemanagement/empact"; 
 form.action = base_url+"/timemanagement/emptimesheets/employeeactivity"; 
 sel_date.value=date;
 sel_date.name="date";
 form.appendChild(sel_date);
 ele_user_id.value=user_id;
 ele_user_id.name="user_id";
 form.appendChild(ele_user_id);
 document.body.appendChild(form);
 form.submit();
}
```

```html
public function employeeactivityAction()
 {   
  
  try{

   $clientsForm = new Timemanagement_Form_empact();
   $empModel = new Timemanagement_Model_empact();
      $user_id=$this->_request->getParam('user_id');
   $sel_date=$this->_request->getParam('sel_date');
   
   $this->view->ermsg = '';
   $this->view->myVar = 1234;
   
   // if($user_id > 0){
   // $clientsForm->view->myVar = 167;//$user_id;
   // $clientsForm->view->ermsg = 'now';
   // error_log($user_id);
   //   }
   error_log($user_id);
   $sel_date=$this->view->date;
   $this->view->form = $clientsForm;
   $this->view->inpage = 'Add';
   //$this->view->assign('user_id', $user_id);

  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
   $this->view->ermsg = 'nodata';
  }
  if($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
   if($clientsForm->isValid($this->_request->getPost())){
    $type_Entry =$this->_request->getParam('type_Of_Entry');
    $level_Intensity=$this->_request->getParam('level_Of_Intensity');
    $description = $this->_request->getParam('description');
    
       //  $user_id =$this->_request->getParam('user_id');
    $date = new Zend_Date();
    $data = array('emp_id'=>25,
     'type_of_entry'=>$type_Entry,
     'level_of_intensity'=>$level_Intensity,
     'activity_desc'=>trim($description),
     'date'=>$date
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i get it, but
If you do:

```
   <?php echo $this->myVar ?>
```

on the view, you will print the data, but you can't send data to separated javascript files, unless you set an session, but its not the case.

can you give some more details?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thank you,

myVar ?> This only for viewing the data , but i need to send the data again to controller,

or can you please give me an example for storing a value in session for Zend php

Comment: for session manipulation, you can use
 $some_data = new Zend_Session_Namespace('data');
anything on this variable will be in your session automatically

have you tried to put the data on some hidden element on the form?